# Virtual Macines in RHEL6

Tags: networking, virtualization, redhat, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

Can we make virtual machines in RHEL6 with each having static ip's and have individual connection from other network and without using a bridge.

Comment: What is the output of 'ip addr show' and 'brctl show'?

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:1f:13:6d:01:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::e61f:13ff:fe6d:128/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: 3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:1f:13:6d:01:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.3.1.7/24 brd 10.3.1.255 scope global eth1
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:1f:13:5f:01:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: bridge0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether e4:1f:13:6d:01:28 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.220/22 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global bridge0
    inet6 fe80::e61f:13ff:fe6d:128/64 scope link

Comment: valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:00:85:88:b2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe85:88b2/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: bridge name bridge id  STP enabled interfaces
bridge0  8000.e41f136d0128 yes  eth0
       vnet0
       vnet1

Answer (score 1):

Either you need a seperate hardware NIC assigned to each virtual machine using [pci passthrough](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-PCI_passthrough.html), or you need to use [bridged networking](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html).

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to go about networking - use a bridge or use NAT. 
The preferred way is to use a bridge, since this places the VM in the same network with the rest of the involved machines, the bridge acting like a virtual hub for the VMs.
What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi dyasny, i configured the host with ip 192.168.125.2 and the virtual machines with static ip's 192.168.125.3-15. The issues came when we moved the server to hosting center and there was lot of connection problems to the VM's.

Comment: Here is the ifconfig of Host:                                 bridge0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E4:1F:13:63:37:2C  
          inet addr:192.168.125.2  Bcast:192.168.125.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr E4:1F:13:63:37:2C  
          
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:54:00:E6:D4:FB  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fee6:d4fb/64 Scope:Link

Comment: Is the issue of network because i assigned the same network range to the VM's as well as the Host. Which is the best solution, change host ip or change VM ip's?How can i map the Changed IP to the Users Assigned IP.